# Selecting 1 of many arrays based on contents in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string:

```
hi - a - something;bye - b - else;huh - c - here)
```

that i'm exploding into multiple arrays

```
array(hi,a,something)
array(bye,b,else)
array(huh,c,here)
```

i only want one of these arrays though and which one depends on the 2nd variable in each array with following criteria:

d > b > a > e > c > anything else

so in this case, i need the code to select array(bye,b,else) as the one to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use a sorting function:

```
$arr=array(
    array(hi,a,something),
    array(bye,b,else),
    array(huh,c,here)
);

usort($arr,'myFunc');
return $arr[1];

function myFunc($a,$b){
  $crit=array('d','b','a','e','c');
  $a2=$a[1];
  $b2=$b[1];
  if(array_search ( $a2 , $crit) > array_search ( $b2 , $crit))
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
}
```